# checkandall.php added to WordPress root directory

Tags: php, wordpress

After logging into one of my WordPress sites today, the Securi plugin has reported that the following files were added:

01/04/2015 - New file added checkandall.php (size: 592)

This sits on the root of my server and contains the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
function GetListFiles($folder,&$all_files){
    $fp=opendir($folder);
    while($cv_file=readdir($fp)) {
        if(is_file($folder."/".$cv_file)) {
        if(is_writable($folder)){
            $all_files[]=$folder."/*";
            }
        }elseif($cv_file!="." && $cv_file!=".." && is_dir($folder."/".$cv_file)){
            GetListFiles($folder."/".$cv_file,$all_files);
        }
    }
    closedir($fp);
}
$all_files=array();
GetListFiles("/var/sites/w/www.mydomain/public_html/",$all_files);
$result = array_unique($all_files);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Can someone with more PHP experience please explain what this is doing? I assume it's a file that has been injected to monitor the rest of my WordPress site.

**Other actions that also concern me:**

01/04/2015 - Plugin deleted: PHP Code for posts (v1.2.0; php-code-for-posts/PHPPostCode.php) ***- Not actioned by me***

01/04/2015 - Plugin deactivated: Sucuri Security - Auditing, Malware Scanner and Hardening  ***- Not actioned by me***

01/04/2015 - Media file added; identifier: 328; name: maink.php; type.  ***- Not actioned by me***

01/04/2015 - Plugin installed: maink.php  ***- Not actioned by me***

Luckily, my host does daily, offsite backups, so I can just do a restore. I'm curious to understand how this happened and what the likely effect of the hack would be.

Comment: The code portion looks to list all folders and files recursively.

Comment: Since WP stores your database as constants in your files, you should change your database credentials.

Comment: Also, change any administrator user password as well as ftp passwords.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get on this now.

Comment: The script checks for all folders that are writable by the server and prints the list when done. It's most likely part of a Wordpress hack, here's [more info on a Malware must die!](http://blog.malwaremustdie.org/2014/05/elf-shared-so-dynamic-library-malware.html) about it. As mentioned above, change your database credentials and `chmod()` properly to avoid another infection.

Comment: Just to help answer your question on how: there are a few scenarios why someone was able to get in. One is brute force attack, which is an automated username/password attempting engine. Depending on the your hosts safeguards or easy username/password combo, intruders can log in by trying thousands of combinations in a matter of seconds. Another  way is if you are using public internet connection (Starbucks or something) and someone on the network inserts themselves between you and your website and captures important data like user/pass.

Comment: If you use a public machine like Internet cafe, someone can hijack your cookies and such. There are a lot of ways a user can gain access to a wordpress site (or any site for that matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is getting a list of all files in all directories from a specific base directory("/var/sites/w/www.mydomain/public_html/") in this case, and prints a list of directories that are writeable to the screen. This is probably for the attacker to find places to upload new scripts to, which they will use to perform further attacks.

It looks like someone got administrative access to your Wordpress site and is using that to upload other scripts to do more damage. That plugin that was installed likely opens up further vulnerabilities for the attacker to exploit. Take the server offline, restore it from backups, change all database and Wordpress admin credentials, then update Wordpress to the latest version.

Take a look at this:
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~markmont/awp/

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm a little puzzled to why this has happened. I've kept everything up to date and followed good security practices.